# Checking the Membership of an element in a stream of rational number

Tags: agda

I want to write a function which takes a rational number and a `Stream` of rationals as input and return `True` if that number is present in that `Stream` else return `False`.

```
-- x ∈ xs means that x is a member of xs.

infix 4 _∈_

data _∈_ {A} : A → Stream A → Set where
  here  : ∀ {x   xs}                   → x ∈ x ∷ xs
  there : ∀ {x y xs} (x∈xs : x ∈ ♭ xs) → x ∈ y ∷ xs
```

This is defined in the library.

I want to write a function of following signature.

```
_ElementOf_ : ∀ {A} → A → Stream A → Bool
```

The problem is that I do not understand how to proceed with `here` and `there`.

Comment: If this is the `Stream` from the standard library, then it's impossible to write `_ElementOf_` for it! That's because `Stream`-s are inifnite, and the function wouldn't terminate if an element is not in the stream, and Agda functions must terminate.